# "based on" or "according to" a certain pattern?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use these terms interchangeably when referring to a pattern?
I found some results for both possibilities so I am wondering whether there is a preferred version, maybe in a certain context?

**For example**:

There are 20 numbers on a board. The instructions are as follows:

> Pick five numbers **based on** a pattern of your choice.

or

> Pick five numbers **according to** a pattern of your choice.

After picking these numbers and showing them to someone else, he/she tries to guess the pattern.

Comment: Can you give an example of someone following the directions you have here? That may help us answer your question. :)

Comment: This is an interesting question... my first feeling is that both are fine, though I have a personal preference for "according to".

Comment: I think you can just say " Pick five numbers in a pattern of your choice"

Answer (score 1):

I would use *based on*, because the pattern determines (is the *basis* for) the numbers you pick.

> Pick five numbers **based on** a pattern of your choice.